# General solution of a linear congruence $\,ax\equiv b\pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying number theory from Introduction to Analytic number theory by Apostol.

I have a doubt in one argument of proof of Theorem 5.14 and I am posting its image.

> My doubt is in 2nd line of 2 nd paragraph how Apostol writes - If y is a solution of (5) then ay $\equiv $ at ( mod m) . How does y being a solution of (5) implies that? 
>   [image]

Can someone please help

Comment: $ay\equiv b\equiv at\pmod m$ because $y,t$ are, by assumption, solutions of (5).

Comment: I added an answer that may help to clarify the idea behind the proof. I can elaborate on that if need be - just post questions in comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person who asked it has abandoned it.

Comment: I don't know why $ax\equiv at (\mod m)\Rightarrow x\equiv t(\mod m/d).$ A book tells me that, $m| a(x - t)\Rightarrow m | d(x - t)$ because if $b | ac,$ then $b | (a, b)c.$ This is because if $b | mn$ and $(b, m) = 1,$ then $b | n.$ This is because $1 = bp + mq\Rightarrow n = bnp + mnq.$ As $b | (bnp + mnq)\Rightarrow b | n.$

Comment: @LuânTăngVăn It has been answered before and I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t\,$ is a root of $(7),$ which, scaled by $d,\,$ shows $t$ is root of $(5)$, so $\,at\equiv b\equiv ay\Rightarrow at\equiv ay,\,$  by transitivity of congruence (being an equivalence relation).

The proof is *poorly* presented. Below is a more *conceptual* presentation that generalizes widely. Like *linear* differential and difference equations (recurrences), for any *linear* congruence $\,ax \equiv b,\,$ it's easy to show (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1233729/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182469/242))  the $\rm\color{darkorange}{general}$ solution is the sum of any $\color{#0a0}{{\rm particular\ solution}\ x_0}\,$ plus the general solution of associated *homogeneous* equation $ax \equiv 0\pmod{\!m},\,$  [which here is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883921/242) $\, m\mid ax\!\iff m/d\mid (a/d)x\!\iff m/d\mid x,\,$ by Euclid & $\,(m/d,a/d)\! =\! (m,a)/d = 1.\,$ Viewed $\!\bmod m\ $ such $\:\!x\:\!$ are the $\,\color{#c00}d\,$ multiples of $\,m/d,\,$ i.e. $\, m/d\,\color{#c00}{\{0,1,2,\ldots, d\!-\!1\}}^{\phantom{|^|}}\!$ [to be [rigorous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295406/242) note $\!\bmod m\!:\,\ x\,\equiv\, k(m/d)\,\equiv\, k(m/d)\bmod m\:\overset{\small\rm\color{#90f}{DL}}\equiv\: m/d\,\color{#c00}{(k\bmod d)}$ by ${\small\rm\color{#90f}{DL}}\!=\!$  [$\!\bmod\!$ Distrib. Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)].
Hence the $\rm\color{darkorange}{general}$ solution is $\!\bmod m\!:\, x\equiv \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\underbrace{\color{#0a0}{x_0} + m/d\ \color{#c00}k^{\phantom{|^{|^.}}\!\!\!}}_{\text{$\rm \color{#0a0}{particular}$ + homogeneous}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!,\ \color{#c00}{0\!\le\! k\!<\! d}\ \ $ [$x_0 = t\,$ in the OP]

**Remark** $ $ Said *structure* of the solution space will be clarified when one studies linear algebra and modules (= linear algebra where the coefficient algebra is a *ring* vs. field)

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) for more on switching back-and-forth between the equivalent linear congruence and its associated Bezout linear equation, and links to handy algorithms for solving such equations.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) for a convenient view of the above in terms of modular (multi-valued) *fractions*