# Prove that unique modular division is possible iff the divisor has modular multiplicative inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It's easy to show that if the divisor has a modular multiplicative inverse under m then dividing by it would be possible. I'd simply multiply both sides of the antecedent below by $b$ and let $x=yb$ be the witness.

$$there\:is\:a\:unique\:y\:such\: that\:
ay=1\:\left(mod\:m\right)\rightarrow there\:is\:a\:unique\:x\:such\: that\: ax=b\:\left(mod\:m\right) where\:b\in \left\{0,1,\:...,\:m-1\right\}
$$However, it doesn't seem as easy when I try to go the other way. Any suggestions?

Comment: The opposite direction is not true. As explained in the linked dupe (and its links, esp. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)) we have  $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ is solvable $\iff  d:=\gcd(a,m)\mid b;\,$ if so there are $\,d\,$ solutions $\bmod m\ \ $

Comment: To make it true you can change it to $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{m}\,$ has a *unique* solution, i.e. the modular fraction $b/a$ uniquely exists. The prior linked post explains this at length from a fractional viewpoint.

Comment: So both ways are true now?

Comment: Yes, after incorporating the above fix it is now true, since, like the first, the second congruence has a unique root $\iff d := \gcd(a,m) = 1\ \ $

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for an introduction to modular fractions.

Comment: I can't see that the answers in any of the links you provided exactly answer my question. I'm trying to prove that if we can perform modular division for any $b$ in ${0,1,..,m-1}$ with $a$ being the divisor under $m$ then the modular multiplicative inverse of $a$ under $m$ must exist (and vice versa.)

Comment: They do - see my prior comment.

Comment: Why do I have a to understand a different question and read its lengthy answer just so I can stumble upon an answer to my straightforward question?

Comment: You only need to read paragraphs 2 & 3 [in said answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), which shows that  when $d>1$ the solution is not unique (or does not exist).

Comment: If you seek something more direct then note that if $d>1$ and $\,x_0\,$ is a solution of $\,ax\equiv b\pmod m\,$ then $\,x_1 := x_0 + m/d\,$ is a different solution $x_1\not\equiv x_0\pmod m,\,$ because $\,m/d \not \equiv 0\pmod m$ are different solutions of the associated homogeneous equation $\,ax\equiv 0\pmod m\,$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488370/242).