# Proof of number of solutions to a linear congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

This is a proof from Abstract Algebra by Beachy and Blair. I had thought I was following it until I got to the last sentence. How does taking any solution and adding multiples of n/d to it produce d many solutions?[image]

Comment: $a\left(x+k\dfrac{n}d\right)\equiv ax+k\dfrac ad n\equiv ax\equiv b\pmod n$, and these are distinct $\pmod n$ for $k=0 ,1,...d-1$

Comment: See the more conceptual presentation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3488370/242) in the linked dupe.