# Constant after integration

Tags: calculus, integration, curves, constants

What is the true significance of the constant "c" that we add after we integrate a curve without applying limits?

Comment: It means there are various functions which differentiated would give the same result of your original integrand.  These various functions differ by constant amounts (which would disappear in the differentiation).

Comment: Have you read this: [Purpose Of Adding A Constant After Integrating A Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94258)?

Comment: For example $\frac{d}{dx} \big(\sin^2(x)\big) = \frac{d}{dx} \big(-\cos^2(x) \big)= \frac{d}{dx} \big(-\frac12\cos(2x) \big)= 2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$ so you cannot say precisely which is the integral of  $2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$.  Saying $\int 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) \, dx = \sin^2(x) +c$ covers all these cases with $c$ being $0$ or $-1$ or $-\frac12$ to cover those three examples

Comment: The significance is that parallel lines exist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  talking in $\Bbb R^2$ after integrating when we obtain a function $g(x)+c$ the set I={$g(x)+c | \forall c\in \Bbb R $} it indicates the entire **Family of Curves** . But when we fix the quantity  'c' to a fixed real number , we are actually indicating a specific curve out of the Family of Curves .That's the role of the integrating constant.

Answer (score -1):

Integration is reverse process of Differentiation.
Suppose,
f(X) = 2X+ 3

f'(X) = 2 ---->(1)

Again,
f(X) = 2X ,
f'(X) = 2---->(2)

Now, if you integrate
2 , we take integral value as

2x+c (because of What I mentioned above. Since, derivative of constant term is 0)

Hence, we don't know wheather it has constant term or not !
That's why we take a arbitrary constant C.

Comment: Use mathjax tools for writing answer. That's only accepted by community.